# Upload video to youtube via URL with python gdata

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

Is it possible to upload a video on youtube with a remote URL (not from the local machine). I am using Youtube API and python gdata tools for this.

I don't have the videos on the server where the script will run, and I want to upload them directly to youtube from a remote URL, instead of downloading them first... Do you know if this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  Not possible.

Long answer: Videos are just data files. So the question becomes: is it possible for a program on Computer A to tell Server B to send a file to Server C using standard internet communication?  YouTube only accepts POST requests for uploading videos, so Server B would need to send this request.  And you can't tell Server B to do this with just a URL.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just interested if youtube has such a feature... It would be easy to implement: They can put an option to enter a URL and the youtube serve receives the URL it can do a wget or something similar to get the video filee