# python youtube api to upload videos from external url

Tags: python, youtube-api

Is it possible to upload a video to Youtube via external URL, not from local machine? I did it with dailymotion but can't make it with Youtube.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711561/upload-video-to-youtube-via-url-with-python-gdata

Comment: that's 3 years ago post, did they make any updates?

Comment: I don't know if they added this feature. For that you have to read the API docs, regarding what features are supported!

Comment: I have read it for 2 days and searching for answers but no luck

Comment: Just post a sample code so that people don't start down voting. :P

Comment: Where would you be uploading the video from, exactly? Looking at the documentation, there's an Error 400: mediaBodyRequired (The request does not include the video content), which leads me to believe that you need to do it locally.

Comment: I want to upload from google drive, which i already did for dailymotion API